# How can I add wrap capability to a QLegend

Tags: c++, qt, qchart

After adding more than 3 items (like all of the examples) to a QChat's QLegend, the legend becomes overcrowded and the text for each series item gets truncated becoming unreadable. I need to be able to resize the attached legend or at lease allow the items to wrap to additional rows.

Is there any way to get a QLegend to wrap series items?